# Why do I need the Identity functor in Idris

Tags: idris

Although Idris is dependently typed, where values can be used freely in types, it still differentiate function `id` and functor `Identity`. Why can't I define Functor instances on `id`:

```
Functor id where
  map = id
```

The type of `id` is `id : a -> a`, why can't `a` be unified with `Type`, so that `map @{Functor id}` has type `(a -> b) -> id a -> id b`, which is just `(a -> b) -> a -> b`

I understand that `Identity` is a type wrapper but why do I need a separate id at type level, just to enable the implementation of typeclass instances.

The only difference of `Identity` and `id` is that `Identity a` cannot be evaluated to `a`, but it’s still a `Type -> Type` function, same as `id {a=Type}` in type.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a function which returns its input value as the result. When you need a function that does nothing to its input except return the same value, then use `id`.

`Identity` is a simple type wrapper which wraps a type `t` to produce a new type `Identity t`, where a value of type `Identity t` is a record containing just one value of the original wrapped type `t`.

Because `Identity` is an algebraic data type, it can implement an interface in Idris. In particular it implements `Monad`.

Sometimes one can define a type constructor that constructs types which implement `Monad`, by first defining a monad transformer that takes a monadic type as one of its parameters. To provide an arbitrary non-monad type as a parameter to such a constructor, first wrap the non-monad type using the `Identity` type constructor.

For an example, see the library module `Control.Monad.Writer`.

Comment: I understand that Identity is a type wrapper but my question is why do I need a separate id at type level, just to enable the implementation of typeclass instances. The only difference is that Identity a cannot be evaluated to a, but it’s still a Type -> Type function, same as id {a=Type} in type.

Comment: If you have a monad transformer, and you want to pass an arbitrary type `t` into it, the monad transformer requires the type `t` to implement Monad, which for arbitrary `t` is not the case. Interface implementations can only be defined for specific data type constructors. By wrapping `t` using `Identity`, you have `Identity t` which represents the same data, but also implements `Monad`.